# Python - np.loadtxt - plotting issues

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a series of graphs using numerical data from multiple text files using the code given below.

The code is working good, however, the plotting is not. The code generates a pdf in which the first page contains a plot with the first set of data taken from the first file (which is fine). However, the second page contains a plot with both the first and second set of data taken from the first and second file. This issue continues till the end and the last page contains a plot plotted with all the data from all the text files.

I need to plot a series of graph such that each graph contains subplots generated using data only one text file.

Please help.

```
Er = np.array([0.0, 100.0, 1000.0, 10000.0]) 
G_star = np.array([1.0, 25.0, 50.0, 100.0, 150.0]) 
k = np.array([0.025, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0, 5.0])

from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
pp = PdfPages('multipage.pdf')

for h in np.arange(0,len(Er),1):
    print "Present Electric Rayleigh no.", Er[h]
    Er_local = Er[h]
    for i in np.arange(0,len(k),1):
       print "Present Wave no.", k[i]
       k_local = k[i]
    for j in np.arange(0,len(G_star),1):
        G_star_local = G_star[j]
        fname = 'QuadraticMap_200_Eigfunc_Pr=1000.00_k=%3.2f_G_star=%03d_Er=%06d.txt' % (k_local, G_star_local, Er_local)
        f1=np.loadtxt(fname)
        y1=f1[:,0]; si1=f1[:,1]; t1=f1[:,2]; phi1=f1[:,3]; u1=f1[:,1]; q1=f1[:,2]; v1=f1[:,3];

        plt.subplot(2, 3, 1)
        plt.plot(y1,si1,'-k',linewidth=1,label= fname)
        plt.title('$\psi$ disturbance',fontsize='5')
        plt.xlabel('$\eta$',fontsize='5',weight='bold')
        plt.ylabel('$\psi$',fontsize='5',weight='bold')
        xticks(fontsize='5',weight='bold')
        yticks(fontsize='5',weight='bold')
        legend(loc='Top right',fontsize='5')
        xlim(0,17)

        plt.subplot(2, 3, 2)
        plt.plot(y1,u1,'-k',linewidth=1)
        plt.title('$u$ disturbance',fontsize='5')
        plt.xlabel('$\eta$',fontsize='5',weight='bold')
        plt.ylabel('$u$',fontsize='5',weight='bold')
        xticks(fontsize='5',weight='bold')
        yticks(fontsize='5',weight='bold')
        xlim(0,17)

        plt.subplot(2, 3, 3)
        plt.plot(y1,v1,'-k',linewidth=1)
        plt.title('$v$ disturbance',fontsize='5')
        plt.xlabel('$\eta$',fontsize='5',weight='bold')
        plt.ylabel('$v$',fontsize='5',weight='bold')
        xticks(fontsize='5',weight='bold')
        yticks(fontsize='5',weight='bold')
        xlim(0,17)

        plt.subplot(2, 3, 4)
        plt.plot(y1,t1,'-k',linewidth=1)
        plt.title('$t$ disturbance',fontsize='5')
        plt.xlabel('$\eta$',fontsize='5',weight='bold')
        plt.ylabel('$t$',fontsize='5',weight='bold')
        xticks(fontsize='5',weight='bold')
        yticks(fontsize='5',weight='bold')
        xlim(0,17)

        plt.subplot(2, 3, 5)
        plt.plot(y1,phi1,'-k',linewidth=1)
        plt.title('$\phi$ disturbance',fontsize='5')
        plt.xlabel('$\eta$',fontsize='5',weight='bold')
        plt.ylabel('$\phi$',fontsize='5',weight='bold')
        xticks(fontsize='5',weight='bold')
        yticks(fontsize='5',weight='bold')
        xlim(0,17)

        plt.subplot(2, 3, 6)
        plt.plot(y1,q1,'-k',linewidth=1)
        plt.title('$q$ disturbance',fontsize='5')
        plt.xlabel('$\eta$',fontsize='5',weight='bold')
        plt.ylabel('$q$',fontsize='5',weight='bold')
        xticks(fontsize='5',weight='bold')
        yticks(fontsize='5',weight='bold')
        xlim(0,17)
        ylim(0,1)
        plt.savefig(pp, format='pdf')

pp.close()
```

Comment: Simplest solution: add `plt.cla()` before `plt.subplot(2, 3, 1)`.

Comment: Thanks! Apparently, adding `plt.close()` after `plt.savefig(pp, format='pdf')` worked.